# Advice for creating scientifically plausable human-animal hybrids?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

What would have to be taken into consideration? What is the limit of human DNA modification? What sort of changes can the human organs tolerate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What has to be taken into consideration within the human body and with human structures when creating human-animal hybrids?

Comment: What kind of animal-human hybrids are we talking about?  Most such creatures  in fiction are anatomically humans with funny ears, fur, and a tail.  To create actual hybrids, e.g. the mythical sphinx or naga, well, you can imagine the anatomical difficulties (land mammal bone structure vs avian bone structure, skeletal structure for an upright stance vs 4 legged stance) and physiological difficulties (warm-blooded mammal vs cold-blooded reptile, oviparous vs viviparous) that make it exceedingly implausible.

Comment: Are you looking for help with establishing a framework for creating plausible hybrids? If this is the case I would suggest defining plausibility and specifying that you are looking for a theoretical framework that can be used to create various beings, rather than a design for a specific being. Please note that this community prefers practical questions and is not very familiar with abstract theoretical problems.

Answer (score 3):

## Homology

A lot of hybrids are destroyed by a poor understanding of which structures are homologous and which aren't

For example, arms, wings, forelegs, and side-fins are all the same structure, and so you can only have one of them (or a single pair of limbs that combines both functions)

Also, most all invertebrate parts, save the eyes, are not homologous to any human part, so feel free to add any insectoid legs and wings

Answer (score 0):

Humans get quite a few auto-immune issues, we have an enormously complex and delicately balanced immune-system, and pregnancy with your hybrid would be a special case involving the foetus and the mother, so:

**[Histocompatibility & Immune-modulation during pregnancy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histocompatibility), [and: 2.](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/06/120607142244.htm)**

You'd think a tissue wouldn't be attacked by it's own body, but it happens all the time. In pregnancy, the mother's immune-system is modulated by the foetus in order so suppress the immune-response such that the foetus, despite being a de-facto foreign-body is not rejected. This can lead to two issues normally, and more-so with the additional proteins being expressed in the hybrid-form:

- 1. The foreign tissues being too-foreign for the immune suppression to have enough of the intended effect, resulting in a mother V.s foetus immune reaction, spontaneous abortion.
- 2. The modulation/suppression of the immune-system being too-extreme, resulting in the mother succumbing to pathogens and dying before term.

Then, after birth, you've the issue of getting the developing child-hybrid to not attack itself ([auto-immune conditions.](https://www.niehs.nih.gov/health/topics/conditions/autoimmune/index.cfm)), the [chimerism](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31001268/) which naturally occurs both-ways between mother and foetus during gestation means that the mother would, after term when no-longer having it's immune-system suppressed by the growing foetus react against the embedded tissues, creating a crisis, perhaps illness, perhaps death. The same goes for the growing hybrid child, it's mother's cells still being present and if substantially different from it's own might cause serious issues.